# Dynamic tablix creation on SSRS

Tags: excel, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

Scenario: I have a table of open orders by vendor, I need to be able to generate an excel file with a list of every vendor's open orders separated on each tab.

I need then need to set up a subscription that would send this excel file to someone who would distribute the sheets to the respective vendors.

The problems: 
- The list of vendors changes frequently therefore I will need to dynamically create and remove vendor tablixs as these changes occur.
- I need to also have each excel sheet labeled dynamically to the correct vendor.

Thank you in advance for you much appreciated help. please let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: I would like to see what you have tried so far. Helping you solve these issues might be a little easier then.

Comment: A few quick pointers as there are plenty of answers on SO about this.

Group by Vendor
Vendor Group properties -> Set pagename property to expression (Vendor name I guess)
Set page breaks between group (I think you have to do this too but maybe try without first)